# Positioning DIV's relatively?

Tags: css, html, position

Is positioning all the `div`s in a page a good technique?

```
div { position:relative; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It establishes positioning contexts that you don't need and may interfere with other things you may do.